# Insert data to Mongob Shard Cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

At first below is my shard cluster I create by Ops Manager:

[image]

I have 2 Mongos and 2 Shard (each shard configure replicates set). I not configure any shard key, I mean not sharded collections esxit in my cluster.

When I use mongos to insert a database for testing purposes, the database store only one Shard.

So I want when I insert a database, data can split and store balance on both shards. And I can query from mongos to get accurate data.

Anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Databases and collections are not sharded automatically: a sharded deployment can contain both unsharded and sharded data. Unsharded collections will be created on the [primary shard](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#primary-shard) for a given database.

If you want to shard a collection you need to take a few steps in the `mongo` shell connected to a `mongos` process for your sharded deployment:

- Run [`sh.enableSharding(<database>)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.enableSharding/) for a database (this is a one-off action per database)
- [Choose a shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#choosing-a-shard-key) using `sh.shardCollection()`

See [Shard a Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/#shard-a-collection) in the MongoDB manual for specific steps.

It is important to choose a good shard key for your data distribution and use case. Poor choices of shard key may result in unequal data distribution or limit your sharding performance. The MongoDB documentation has more information on the considerations and options for choosing a shard key.

If you are not sure a collection if a collection sharded or want to see a summary of the current data distribution, you can use [`db.collection.getShardDistribution()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getShardDistribution/)  in the `mongo` shell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement **Zone Range** so according the range the data will be stored for each shred.

The code bellows helps you to create zones :

For the zone01 :

```
sh.addShardTag("rs1", "zone01")
sh.addTagRange("myDB.col01", { num: 1 }, { num: 10 }, "zone01")
```

For the zone02 :

```
sh.addShardTag("rs2", "zone02")
sh.addTagRange("myDB.col01", { num: 11 }, { num: 20 }, "zone02")
```

This will help you [Manage Shard Zones](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-shard-zone/)

Comment: It not solve my problem. I do not want to use shard-key now. I just want when I insert a data, the data will store on both of shard. Do you see the image I upload ?

Comment: There just two ways to shred you data :

1- Ranged Sharding
2- Hashed Sharding

you have to choose one of this i'm sorry.

Comment: So if I cannot shard data without two ways above. I wonder how mongos choose shard to store data when I insert. I see all data store only in shard 1, why it not choose store on shard 2.

Comment: I dont know precisely which one mongo choose by default, it must be the first shard (all data will go to it).

Comment: I use mongorestore -h mongos-host
Data always store on one Shard.
So if mongos can not choose other shard, how I manual to insert to other shard

Comment: I dont know how to force insert to a specific shard, i updated the answer with how to easily create shard zones with mongo

Comment: @MercuryTrivival You need to shard a collection in order to distribute data for that collection across multiple shards. Data imports/updates in a sharded deployment should always be done via `mongos`. Zone sharding (as mentioned in this answer) is an advanced option to influence the distribution of data in a sharded collection where specific locality is desirable (typically where a deployment spans multiple data centres or has tiered storage). For the common sharding use case it is sufficient to choose a suitable shard key and allow the balancer to take care of migrating data between shards.

Comment: I try Hashed Sharding with Shard Key ( _id). I see data distribute on two Shard. But another problem is I can not get accurate data count when use DB. collection.aggregate(). I do this command on two mongos and each mongos have a haft of data. sum the results of two  mongos is exactly count. How I can deal with the issue